# ckeditor integration in flex web app failed

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, ckeditor

I followed [CKEditor Running in Flex and AIRe](http://blog.aboutme.be/2009/10/25/ckeditor-running-in-flex-and-air/) to embed Ckeditor in flex web app .

the integration is perfect in Chrome and FF .  but fails in IE (11) so the controls are not visible .

I tried many version of ckeditor (even last one 4.3) and the result is always the same : 
the textArea is visible but all other controls are not .

Answer (score 0):

I seems that Turning wmode to transparent

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

does resolve the issue in ie 11 .

still a resize issue in ie  (worth another thread) .